# Decrypt with java and AES file encrypted in Obj-C

Tags: java, objective-c, aes

I have a file which is encrypted with obj-c code:

```
NSMutableData *fileData = [NSMutableData new];
// Get file data.
[[self encrypt::fileData WithKey:@"SOME_KEY"]]

- (NSMutableData*) encrypt:(NSMutableData*)data WithKey: (NSString *) key
{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyBuffer[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyBuffer, sizeof(keyBuffer) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    [key getCString: keyBuffer maxLength: sizeof(keyBuffer) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // encrypts in-place, since this is a mutable data object
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    size_t returnLength = ([data length] + kCCKeySizeAES256) & ~(kCCKeySizeAES256 - 1);

    char* returnBuffer = malloc(returnLength * sizeof(uint8_t) );

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128 , kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                 keyBuffer, kCCKeySizeAES128, nil,
                                 [data bytes], [data length],
                                 returnBuffer, returnLength,
                                 &numBytesEncrypted);

    if(result == kCCSuccess)
        return [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:returnBuffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    else
        return nil;
}
```

I want to read this file with java. I am trying

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
// What is salt ??
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("SOME_KEY", salt, 65536, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(plaintext);
```

I don't know anything with obj-c. Do you think I could get this done ? Thank you.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the Objective-C encryption code?  If not, please post the rest of it.

Comment: I edit with the code that encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");` since the Objective-C code is using ECB instead of CBC (you ought to use CBC or CTR instead of ECB, but in this case it doesn't look like you have a choice)

Also, use `SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec("SOME_KEY".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");` since the Objective-C code is simply using the raw bytes from the password to generate a key (rather than using a cryptographic key generator like you're doing).  "SOME_KEY" needs to be the same password used by the Objective-C code.  In addition, "SOME_KEY".getBytes("UTF-8") needs to be exactly 16 bytes, so if necessary you need to truncate it to 16 bytes or else pad it with 0's to 16 bytes.

Comment: I did what you suggest, but I have: Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: @Baptiste Pernet Post the last 16 bytes of the Objective-C output / Java input so I can see how it's padded

Comment: , -19, 87, -27, -113, 98, 80, -77, 57, -60, 31, -68, 73, 103, 51, -36, 50]

Comment: Yeah, that's not padded correctly - it should be 01; or 02, 02; or 03, 03, 03; etc

Comment: What do the first 16 bytes look like?  I suppose it's possible that the byte array got reversed somehow

Comment: -91, -114, -35, -46, -11, -89, -119, -37, -73, 9, -110, 16, 58, 48, 71, -72, 50

Comment: So the byte array didn't somehow get reversed.  Is this the Java input you're posting, or the Objective-C output?  If it's the former, then confirm that it matches the latter - somehow the encrypted data is getting corrupted